# Regular expression to match optional segments of a URI?

Tags: php, regex

Currently, I have a simple router class that takes URIs and attempts to match them to the incoming request URI. A simple example of a route it might try to match to the request URI would be:

```
/user/([0-9]+)
```

So, this would match a request URI of "user/1".

Now I'm trying to match optional parameters. This works:

```
/user([/0-9]?)
```

However, it seems like this would allow any number of slashes in the segment. How can I force the optional segment to be preceded by **one** slash and then numbers?

Comment: BTW, this is not a parameter, it's a resource. A parameter list is identified by `?`.

Comment: Upvote, because its Taylor Otwell :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
/user(/[0-9]+)?
```

It will match "/user" followed by "/" plus one or more digits or "/user" alone. If you want to group the digits only you can enclose it in a non-capturing group:

```
/user(?:/([0-9]+))?
```

You can enclose it in `^` and `$` in the call to `preg_match`:

```
preg_match( "/^\/user(?:\/([0-9]+))?$/", "/user/1234", $m);
print_r($m);
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working for me, but that may be because of how I am doing the preg_match... here is the entire statement:

    preg_match('#^/user(/[0-9]+)?$#',...)

Comment: I'm not sure why lookaheads are involved, `print preg_match('#^/user/[0-9]*$#', "/user/1");` works fine for me since `+?` is the same as `*`.

Comment: @inTide wouldn't the "/" after "user" be required in your example?

Comment: @Taylor Oh yeah, that's true, the answer was correct, I mistook `?:` for `?=`. Try `preg_match('#^/user(/?[0-9]*)$#', "/user/1");` which is basically his answer worded differently.

Comment: @inTide.. Hmm, still doesn't seem to match "/user".

Comment: @Taylor What php version? My `print preg_match('#^/user(/?[0-9]*)$#', "/user");` is printing `1`. Btw, move to chat if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @inTide ... but it will also match `/user1234` or `/user/`.

Comment: @Howard Oh, right, I'm trying to find out why he can't use your version. For me your regex matches `/users` or `/userswhoaren'tactuallyusers`, I think you need to specify end of string with `$`.

Comment: @inTide: add `^` and `$`: `preg_match("/^\/user(?:\/([0-9]+))$/", "/users", $m);` will show no match.

Comment: @Howard: do you know how to get your latest example to match "/users" but not /users1111? Everything seems to work except that.

Comment: @TaylorOtwell: Do you want to match only "/users" or also "/users/1234"?

Comment: @Howard: Your "/user(?:/([0-9]+))?" examples work perfectly except it matches /user1234, which I'm not trying to match on. If anything comes after /user, it must a slash followed by numbers.

Comment: @Howard: that example doesn't allow just "/user" to match. So if I add the "?" to the end of it, then "/user1234" matches when I don't want it to. Wow, thanks for all the help guys. Sorry this is so confusing.

Comment: @Howard let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1427/discussion-between-taylorotwell-and-howard)

Comment: @TaylorOtwell Sorry, "?" was missing in last expression. Now it should be fine, see [here](http://ideone.com/2az2o)